# How can I receive null as a parameter in function type in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, null, nullable

I'm wondering how we can receive null values as an argument in function type in Kotlin.
Here I attach the code:

```
fun main() {
    println(sum?.invoke(null,20))
}

typealias Arithmatic = ((Int, Int) ->  Int)?
val sum : Arithmatic = { ValueA, ValueB -> ValueA + ValueB }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all variables in Kotlin, function references normally cannot be null. In order to allow a null value, you have to add a `?` to the end of the type definition, like so:

In the example you have given, you have mentioned that `ValueA` is of type `Int`. So, in that case, you can't pass null as it's parameter.

If you want to pass `null` for `ValueA`, you have to mention that `ValueA` is indeed **nullable**. We can do this by putting `?` after the variable type.

And also in the function body, you have to mention how to execute in case if the `ValueA` is `null`. For example you can change your code like this:

```
typealias Arithmatic = ((Int?, Int) ->  Int)
val sum : Arithmatic = { ValueA, ValueB -> ValueA ?: 0 + ValueB }

fun main() {
    println(sum.invoke(null,20))

}
```

Here I changed `Int` to `Int?` which means I'm saying that this parameter can be `null`. Also, in `ValueA ?: 0`, I'm saying that if `ValueA` is not `null`, use it and if it's `null`, use `0`.

You can read about null safety more here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. It solves the problem.